# rbind a filename named by loop within loop

Tags: r

I am trying to create a loop to create a dataframe that has a sum of a variable based on a rolling period of ten years. I think I got that bit figured, but I don't know how to rbind within the loop if the name is also assigned in the loop. So the loop just replaces itself.

dummy data setup:

```
library('dplyr')
library('sf')
library('tigris')


florida <- counties(state = "Florida", year = 2010) %>% 
  select(c(GEOID10)) %>% rename("geoid" = "GEOID10") %>% st_drop_geometry()

florida_annual <- florida %>% mutate(year = 1900, disaster1 = sample(0:5, 67, TRUE), disaster2 = sample(0:5, 67, TRUE) )

for(x in 1901:1990){
  temp <- florida %>% mutate(year = x, disaster1 = sample(0:5, 67, TRUE), disaster2 = sample(0:5, 67, TRUE))
  florida_annual <- rbind(florida_annual, temp)
  rm(temp)
  
}
```

Loop that needs an rbinding effect somewhere:

```
for(x in 70){for(j in 1900:1910){
  filename <- paste0("tab_", x)
  assign(filename, florida_annual[florida_annual$year >= j & florida_annual$year <= j + x,] %>% 
           group_by(geoid) %>% 
           summarise(cat_total = sum(disaster1),
                     .groups = 'drop') %>% mutate(year_group = paste0(j,"_", j+x))
  )
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear to me exactly what you want. If you just want a data frame of file names, you simply create a dummy data frame before your loop and `rbind` within.

```r
library('dplyr')
library('sf')
library('tigris')


florida <- counties(state = "Florida", year = 2010) %>% 
  select(c(GEOID10)) %>% 
  rename("geoid" = "GEOID10") %>% 
  st_drop_geometry()

florida_annual <- florida %>%
  mutate(year = 1900, disaster1 = sample(0:5, 67, TRUE), disaster2 = sample(0:5, 67, TRUE) )

for(x in 1901:1990){
  temp <- florida %>% 
    mutate(year = x, 
           disaster1 = sample(0:5, 67, TRUE), 
           disaster2 = sample(0:5, 67, TRUE))
  florida_annual <- rbind(florida_annual, temp)
  rm(temp)
  
}

files <- data.frame()

for(x in 1:70){
  for(j in 1900:1910){
    filename <- paste0("tab_", x)
    assign(
      filename, florida_annual[florida_annual$year >= j & florida_annual$year <= j + x,] %>% 
        group_by(geoid) %>% 
        summarise(cat_total = sum(disaster1),
                  .groups = 'drop') %>% 
        mutate(year_group = paste0(j,"_", j+x))
    )
    files <- rbind(files, filename)
  }
}
```